# Using a passed in parameter value to set PATH variables in a batch file

Tags: windows, batch-file, parameters, path, filepath

Right now I have a batch file that sets the PATH variable to all of the required directories.(there is actually a bunch more required directories, i just took them out so the code snippet would not be too long)

```
@echo off

set PATH=D:/src/trunk/build/bin;D:/src/trunk/build/bin/CoreTools;D:/src/trunk/build/bin/Plugins/Extensions;D:/src/trunk/build/bin/Plugins/CustomUI
set DEBRIEF_INSTALL_DIR=D:/src/trunk/DebriefSuite/D3D_Installation
set READERS=D:/src/trunk/build/bin/CoreTools/Readers
set BINARY_DIR=D:/src/trunk/build

cd D:/src/trunk/build/bin

start PROGRAM.exe --ConfigFile="D:/src/trunk/DebriefSuite/Installation/config/Projects/config.xml" ^
                  --Mode-File="D:/src/trunk/DebriefSuite/Installation/config/Projects/Common/anotherconfig.xml" ^
                  --Env:Bin="D:/src/trunk/build/bin"


cd D:/src/trunk
```

It works fine, but all of the directories are hard-coded. This needs to be able to work for other computers that might have their root directory in a different location. I need to be able to pass in a root directory (something like "D:\different_root_location") and substitute it in to each place in this code that currently says "D:\src\trunk". The problem is, i am not sure what the syntax would be for something like this. I am new to writing batch files. I tried doing something like

```
SET ROOTDIR=%1 .....
```

And then

```
 set PATH=%ROOTDIR%/build/bin;%ROOTDIR%/build/bin/CoreTools;%ROOTDIR%/build/bin/Plugins/Extensions;%ROOTDIR%/build/bin/Plugins/CustomUI ..........

start PROGRAM.exe --ConfigFile="%ROOTDIR%/DebriefSuite/Installation/config/Projects/config.xml" ^
```

but it did not work. I'm not really sure how to make this work! Also, any links to good sources of information about writing batch files in general would be extremely helpful since i am starting out!

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by it didnt work? I just tried a batch file that does exactly that and it seems to be working fine. Note that you can use %1 instead of %ROOTDIR% in the rest of your batch file...

Comment: I am not sure why, but the PROGRAM.exe (which needs all of the previous set up to work) didn't run like it did when the path was hardcoded. I am wondering if there is some other problem that is not this syntax.

Comment: Are you certain that you need all those folders in the same tree, on the path??

Answer (score 0):

Change your line so it includes the original path as well.

From this:

```
set PATH=D:/src/trunk/build/bin...
```

to this: (and Windows uses `\` and not `/` even though it works in some cases)

```
set PATH=%path%;D:\src\trunk\build\bin....
```